# Limiting ListView with AsyncTask Using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am developing app just like YOUTUBE. I am getting data from the server and showing it in listview. Because data is too big so i want to restrict list view to 5 items and then when I scroll down to the bottom of listview it should add 5 more item.

I am calling ASyncTask from fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myList);
    New.jsonAsyncTask.execute("my url select_video.php?");
}
```

Now I have separate JsonAsyncTask Class because I am calling it from 3 fragments just like above mentioned way..

```
public   class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<SetDatails>> {

ListView listView1;
Context context1;
List<SetDatails> videoLiast1;
private static int tab_id;


public JSONAsyncTask(ListView listView, List<SetDatails> videoLiast,Context context,int id) {
    this.listView1 = listView;
    this.context1 = context;
    this.videoLiast1 = videoLiast;
    tab_id=id;
}



@Override
protected List<SetDatails> doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader myReader = null;


    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream myInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myInputStream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);

        }

        String Json_data = buffer.toString();

        videoLiast1 = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject parentObj = new JSONObject(Json_data);
        JSONArray dataArray = parentObj.getJSONArray("data");
        JSONObject tabObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(tab_id);
        JSONArray videoArray = tabObject.getJSONArray("videos");
        for (int i = 0; i < videoArray.length(); i++) {
            int len=dataArray.length();
            SetDatails setDatails = new SetDatails();
            JSONObject arrayChild = videoArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String vid_ID = arrayChild.getString("id");
            setDatails.setVidID(vid_ID);

            String movie_title = arrayChild.getString("name");
            setDatails.setTitle(movie_title);

            String movie_catagory = arrayChild.getString("category_name");
            setDatails.setGenre(movie_catagory);


            videoLiast1.add(setDatails);
        }

        return videoLiast1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (myReader != null) {
                myReader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}


protected void onPostExecute(List<SetDatails> videoList) {
    super.onPostExecute(videoList);
    if(videoList!=null) {
        try {
            MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(context1, videoList);
                listView1.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have created an Array adapter to fill list view.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetDatails>{

public static int count =5;
List<SetDatails> videoList;

MyListAdapter(Context context,List<SetDatails> object){
    super(context,R.layout.tab2_bookchilds,object);
    videoList = object;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_bookchilds, parent, false);

    TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    title.setText(videoList.get(position).getTitle());

    ImageView imgV_Thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgV_thumbnail);
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(videoList.get(position).getThumbnail())
            .error(R.drawable.icon_white)
            .into(imgV_Thumbnail);


    return view;
}
```

}

I have searched a lot and many people suggest getCount() method although I tried a lot to use this method but don't know how to do that.
Please guys help me because my app is ready to upload but I can't solve this one issue.

Comment: What is the problem, i.e. in which way does your code not meet your requirements?

Comment: everything is working fine. only thing I want is that my server send 1000 videos to me. which I am getting via ASynctask and adding to listView. It takes almost 15 minutes to load whole listview. I want to limit list view to show only 10 items at a time and when i scroll down to listview it should add 10 more and so on

Comment: Refer..http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html Try search like 'load more item in scroll end' and 'lazy loading' you will get it..

Comment: can you tell me how to alter my code to get this functionality